# While creating test cases on DevOps i am getting error as Steps exceeds the maximum allowed length of 1048576

Tags: azure-devops, devops

While creating manual test cases on the DevOps platform, I am getting the following error after 19 steps.
Error: TF401262: Value of long text field Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps exceed the maximum allowed length of 1048576.

I am adding *Action* and the *expected result* fields for each step.
Expected Results contains text and reference screenshots.
After the 19th step, it is not accepting screenshots in the "expected result" field.

[image]

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While creating test cases on DevOps i am getting error as Steps exceeds the maximum allowed length of 1048576

Generally String fields take a max of `255` characters. PlainText/HTML will take a max of `32K`. If it crosses this limits, you can try to store it to a file and add it as an attachment:

[image]